# How to require `luafile` not in a subdirectory

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua, lua

in my config of `init.lua` ,I want to load a `luafile` from anywhere or any directory

#### so : can I source it without function `vim.cmd()`

```
vim.cmd('luafile /full/path/to/file.lua')
```

Comment: Can you use the [require](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html) function?

Comment: Or [dofile](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.html)?

Comment: yah is `require` function, it works for file in subdirectory fine ,  but I can't resource for example from home e.g `~/test.lua` or `/opt/test.lua`